# Trying to call callback after S3.putobject

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

kinda new to aws and javascript and i am trying to achieve the following, uploading a photo using binary support and on my return value adding status paramater to be later used in API Gateway

```
var params = {
  Key: key,
  Body: image,
};
this.s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    callback(null,{newValue: "This is my test value"});
  }
});
```

the code works fine if I comment out the callback line, but crashes otherwise.
 Any tips on how to fix it will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The call structure should be as mentioned over [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property)

```
putObject(params = {}, callback)
```

Your code can be:

```
var params = {
  Key: key,
  Body: image,
};
var newValue = ""
this.s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        this.newValue = "This is my test value";
    }
});
```

Here 'function(err, data) {}' represents 'callback'

Answer (score 0):

Rajana is correct. To add on this: this is a core functionality of JS (or functional programming). The `putObject` function accepts two parameters: `params`, an object containing parameters and `callback` which is a function that is executed inside the `putObject` function when completed. So you don't call `callback`, `putObject` calls `callback`.

So you create a function, and it as a function argument of the `putObject` function. So this would also work:

```
const params = { some: 'params'};
const fn = function(err) { console.log(err); }
this.s3.putObject(params, fn);
```

But you can also define the function in the argument (making it an anonymous function), what you did in your example.

Comment: yea but my issue is that i want to return a value back to an end point, how can i pass a value on this callback so it will be part of the response.

Comment: you can't do that, but you can use how JS using scoping. This works:

`const x = 'hi';
s3.putObject(params, function(){ 
   console.log(x);
}`

See https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript for more info. Basically if you define a variable outside the function, you can use it inside the function.